# Code Igniter - not showing the entry I need

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, distinct

I have the following code to get one line for each MAC with the LATEST state. The problem I have is that I get one line but not with the latest state but rather with the earliest.

```
function get_active_devices($min_duration, $max_duration)
{
    //get all active devices DESC order
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->group_by('mac');
    $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
    $this->db->select('data.mac, state, time, iot_bo.notified, iot_bo.op_state, iot_bo.Name');
    $this->db->where('time >', time()-$max_duration);
    $this->db->where('time <', time()-$min_duration);
    $this->db->join('iot_bo', 'iot_bo.mac = data.mac');
    $this->db->where('iot_bo.op_state', '1');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the query without the distinct and groupBy first? May be the result you want isn't in the total result set to begin with. Because there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your use of db methods as it is.

Comment: yes, I have tried it and it rerturns the right results